# Make Edittext only 1 time editable

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an Edittext that should only be editable one time. After the User edited the text, it should be not clickable anymore. 
Is there anyway to shut off the edit function? Or is the best way to go here with an extra TextView and make it visible when the text was edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a flag in **SharedPreferences** as first time edit or any thing you want. By setting it, you can check whether the editing is already performed or not.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(preferences.getString("isFirstTime", "true").equals("true")){
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("isFirstTime","false");
            editor.apply();
}
```

So in else you can do `EditText.setEnabled(false);`

Its one way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1st Place you need a boolean flag that tell you when to disabled editText.

```
 boolean isEditTextUsed = false;
```

You can just make it disabled when isEditText=true;

```
  if(isEditTextUsed)
      yourEditText.setEnabled(false);
```

To change isEditTextUsed check to true you need to addListener to your EditText

```
    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       isEditTextUsed=true;
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
   });
```

Then save it to sharedprefrences.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bool value to check edit:

```
 if(edited == true){
   Edittext.setClickable(false);
}
```

if you want make it visible:

```
   Edittext.setAlpha(0);
```

hope this help